# Steam Web API: Where I can find the profile status public/private?

Tags: api, steam

Where can I find steam profile status? I mean public profile or private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29), you can check the `communityvisibilitystate` property:

> This represents whether the profile is visible or not, and if it is
> visible, why you are allowed to see it. Note that because this WebAPI
> does not use authentication, there are only two possible values
> returned: 1 - the profile is not visible to you (Private, Friends
> Only, etc), 3 - the profile is "Public", and the data is visible. Mike
> Blaszczak's [post on Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=31955251&postcount=3) says, "The community visibility state
> this API returns is different than the privacy state. It's the
> effective visibility state from the account making the request to the
> account being viewed given the requesting account's relationship to
> the viewed account."